# How to specify Array like class in JSDocs

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a class which is in some ways is like an array.

First there is a generic part that can be accessed with dot notation like:

```
myclass.customerlist

myclass.clientlist

myclass.some_dynamic_list_i_added_on_the_fly
```

i.e. there are generic properties of type Array, maybe documented like this:

```
{Object.<string, Array>}
```

But also like an array it has certain specific methods

```
/**
* @param {string} name
*/
myclass.loaddata(name)
```

loaddata would be a member of myclass and have a string param

I can't see how to specify a class that has known members and also some generic properties that may have any name but are always of a specific type.